# specific values count in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ('A', 'A', 'Cat'),
    ('A', 'A', 'Dog'),
    ('A', 'A', 'Cat'),
    ('A', 'B', 'Dog'),
    ('B', 'B', 'Rat'),
    ('B', 'C', 'Cat'),
    ('B', 'C', 'Cat')
], columns=['id', 'group', 'Animal'])
```

I want to group it by `id` and `group` and calculate the occurrence  of `Cat` in each group. An example output will be:

```
[2, 0, 0, 2]
```

2 `cat` in group `AA`,

0 `cat` in group `AB`,

0 `cat` in group `BB`,

2 `cat` in group `BC`

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a conditional count after groupby on a Pandas Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752601/how-to-do-a-conditional-count-after-groupby-on-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need `mask` + `groupby`:

```
df['Animal'] = df['Animal'].mask(df['Animal'].ne('Cat'))
df.groupby(['id', 'group'])['Animal'].count().tolist()
```

```
[2, 0, 0, 2]
```

Comment: Note: `ne` is "not equal"

Answer (score 6):

You can using `value_counts`

```
df.groupby(['id','group']).Animal.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0).loc[:,'Cat'].tolist()
Out[144]: [2, 0, 0, 2]
```

More info return before the last step .loc

```
df.groupby(['id','group']).Animal.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[145]: 
Animal    Cat  Dog  Rat
id group               
A  A        2    1    0
   B        0    1    0
B  B        0    0    1
   C        2    0    0
```

Answer (score 5):

Your question is very similar (if not duplicate) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752601/how-to-do-a-conditional-count-after-groupby-on-a-pandas-dataframe).

When you want to perform some aggregation which are not part of pandas (e.g. `sum`, `max`, `min`) then you should use the [apply method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html).

Please note that `apply` *can be slower*, so don't start using everywhere.

Now, for your question, you start with grouping by:

```
df.groupby(by=["id", "group"])
```

Then, you select the `Animal` column from the groups:

```
df.groupby(by=["id", "group"])['Animal']
```

At this point, you have values from the `Animal` column for each different group, ready for any aggregation.

Let's define a function to count `Cat`s in a pandas `Series`:

```
def count_cat(series):
    return (series == 'Cat').sum()
```

All you have to do now, is to pass this function to the `apply` method, like the following:

```
df.groupby(by=["id", "group"])['Animal'].apply(count_cat).reset_index(name='count_cat')
```

And the result would be:

|  | id | group | count_cat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | A | 2 |
| 1 | A | B | 0 |
| 2 | B | B | 0 |
| 3 | B | C | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

if 0 values are not important than you can try:

```
list(df[df['Animal']=='Cat'].groupby(['id', 'group']).count()['Animal'])
```

Sorry for my English