# How to check condition on multiple columns after using groupby on pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have following df:

```py
data = [
    ['a', 'one', 10],
    ['a', 'two', 10],
    ['b', 'one', 13],
    ['b', 'two', 100],
    ['c', 'two', 100],
    ['c', 'one', 100],
    ['d', 'one', 100],
    ['d', 'one', 10
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['key1', 'key2', 'key3'])
```

```
key1    key2    key3
0   a   one 10
1   a   two 10
2   b   one 13
3   b   two 100
4   c   two 100
5   c   one 100
6   d   one 100
7   d   one 10
```

I need to group by `key1`,

- search for `key2 == 'one'` (for single occurrence result = OK, for 0 or >1 = NOK),
- also additionally check if `key3 == 10` or `100` then OK, anything else is NOK.

As result I should have `OK` or `NOK`. How can I get something like the following as output?

```
key1  result
a   ok
b   nok
c   ok
d   nok
```

I found a similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45752601/how-to-do-a-conditional-count-after-groupby-on-a-pandas-dataframe) but without additional check for `key3`. What I have so far is the following:

```
test = df.groupby('key1')['key2'].apply(lambda x:(x=='one').sum()).reset_index(name='result')
test['result'].where(~(test['result'] > 1), other='nok', inplace=True)
test['result'].replace([0, 1], ['nok', 'ok'], inplace = True)
```

When I run this code, it gives me following output:

```
key1    result
0   a   ok
1   b   ok
2   c   ok
3   d   nok
```

How can I add the check for `key3`?

Comment: Please put your dataframe as text rather than images. It will help you get more answers.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can try:

```py
def fn(x):
    # filter "one"
    x = x[x['key2'] == 'one']

    # there are zero or >1, return "nok"
    if len(x) == 0 or len(x) > 1:
        return 'nok'

    # is the single `key3` 10 or 100? If yes, return "ok"
    if x['key3'].iat[0] in [10, 100]:
        return 'ok'

    # otherwise "nok"
    return 'nok'

out = df.groupby('key1').apply(fn).reset_index(name="result")
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  key1 result
0    a     ok
1    b    nok
2    c     ok
3    d    nok
```

Comment: quick question, if I want for example to change 'one' for another value and take it as an input to fn(x, key2_var). How should I call this function inside of apply(fn)?

Comment: @KokeAbeke You could call it like `out = df.groupby('key1').apply(lambda x: fn(x, "other value"))`

Answer (score 1):

One-liner using:

- `groupby('key1')['key2'].value_counts().xs('one', level='key2') == 1)` for the check on `key2`
- `groupby('key1')['key3'].unique()` to get `key3` values for each `key1`
- `isin([10, 100]).all(axis=1)` to check condition on `key3`

```py
pd.DataFrame({"result": ((df.groupby("key1")["key2"].value_counts().xs("one", level="key2") == 1) & (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip(df.groupby("key1")["key3"].unique().index, df.groupby("key1")["key3"].unique().values)), orient="index").isin([10, 100, np.nan]).all(axis=1))).replace([True, False], ["ok", "nok"]),})
```

It is ~2x slower than using `groupby().apply()`. See comparison below:

```py
def fast(): # from @Adrej Kesely (10035985)
    def fn(x):
        # filter 'one'
        x = x[x['key2'] == 'one']

        # there are zero or >1, return 'nok'
        if len(x) == 0 or len(x) > 1:
            return 'nok'

        # is the single `key3` 10 or 100? If yes, return 'ok'
        if x['key3'].iat[0] in [10, 100]:
            return 'ok'

        # otherwise 'nok'
        return 'nok'
    return df.groupby('key1').apply(fn).reset_index(name='result')

%timeit fast()
# 677 µs ± 13.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

def slow():
    return pd.DataFrame({"result": ((df.groupby("key1")["key2"].value_counts().xs("one", level="key2") == 1) & (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(zip(df.groupby("key1")["key3"].unique().index, df.groupby("key1")["key3"].unique().values)), orient="index").isin([10, 100, np.nan]).all(axis=1))).replace([True, False], ["ok", "nok"]),})

%timeit slow()
# 1.42 ms ± 36.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Documentation for methods used:

- [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html?highlight=value_counts#pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts) to count occurrences
- [`xs()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html?highlight=xs#pandas.DataFrame.xs) to get a cross section of a data frame
- [`unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html?highlight=groupby%20unique#pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique)
- [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html?highlight=isin#pandas.DataFrame.isin) to check whether there are `key3` values that are not in the "ok" list
- [`all(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html?highlight=all#pandas.DataFrame.all) to check truth values by row
- [`replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html?highlight=replace#pandas.Series.replace) to replace bools with `"ok"` and `"nok"`

Comment: Hi @Joshua, your code is kinda advanced one for me, thank you though)

Comment: No worries! It was mostly as a fun exercise since you already had a working answer from Andrej. Good luck!